# Get field name in write method got error in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

When I edit the sale order and save it, the credit and debit fields got a none type error. How can I solve it?

***Python code:***

```
@api.model
def create(self,vals):
    logging.info("create Mehtod+++++++++++++++++++++")
    logging.info(type(vals.get('credit')))
    if vals.get('credit') < vals.get('debit'):
        vals['check'] = True 
        logging.info("Create fisrt++++++++++++++++")
    else:
        vals['check'] = False
        logging.info("Create second++++++++++++++")
    return super(sale_credit, self).create(vals)

def write(self,vals):
    logging.info("Write Mehtod+++++++++++++++++++++++")
    # logging.info(vals['debit'])
    logging.info(type(vals.get('credit')))
    logging.info(vals)

    if vals['credit'] >= vals['debit']:
        logging.info("FIrst write+++++++++++++")
        vals['check'] = False
    else:
        vals['check'] = True
    return super(sale_credit, self).write(vals)
```

I got this error log. I have the field credit and debit float field but I don't know why I got this error.

```
File "/home/akkl/odoo13_ENTERPRISE/odoo13_5555/odoo13_5555-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1314, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/akkl/odoo13_ENTERPRISE/odoo13_5555/odoo13_5555-server/odoo/api.py", line 387, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/akkl/odoo13_ENTERPRISE/odoo13_5555/odoo13_5555-server/odoo/api.py", line 374, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/akkl/UMG/customer_credit_limit/models/models.py", line 115, in write
    if vals['credit'] >= vals['debit']:
KeyError: 'credit'
```

Answer (score 0):

First that's not a NoneType Error but a KeyError, which means the used key `'credit'` is not in the dictionary `vals`. Which in context of Odoo's write method just means, the field wasn't changed.

Wouldn't it be easier to compute `check`?

```py
# store=True if you want to let users search on the field
check = fields.Boolean(compute="_compute_check")  

@api.depends('debit', 'credit')
def _compute_check(self):
    for record in self:
        if record.credit >= record.debit:
            record.check = False
        else:
            record.check = True
```

Comment: Why exactly then?

Comment: I have button that invisible is depend on that check field and I want to show this button after clicked save.@CZoellner